# Azure/PHP - The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Tags: php, azure

We are trying to deploy a PHP application via zip deployment on Azure but it sends out below error:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
> changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

We can see our URL with the route of `/home` but it is not loading the desired webpage. In local it was working fine.

Any ideas around this?

UPDATE - Tried adding the web.config with contents as below (but unsure if this is related to PHP or our project)- it DIDN'T work

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: web.config files are for .NET projects, nothing to do with PHP

Comment: thanks for the info, @ADyson how to solve this for PHP app?

Comment: you must use install IIS web server in Azure
ues this linke for deploy laravel in Azure

https://coderonfleek.medium.com/hosting-a-laravel-application-on-azure-web-app-b55e12514c46

Comment: @ADyson you're wrong.... you can define rewrite rules and allowed contents such as woff, woff2, etc using web.config  for non .net apps

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio  Maybe so, but that's assuming the environment is Windows with IIS. OP didn't specify the O/S or webserver involved. PHP is more commonly deployed on Linux.

Comment: @GOK what's your web server?

Comment: You need to write a .htaccess file